# How to connect to a second database using Angular Fire?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have this code:

```
import { FirebaseApp } from "@angular/fire/compat";
import {
  AngularFirestore
} from "@angular/fire/compat//firestore";

import {
  initializeFirestore
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";

import { firestoreInstance$ } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    const firebaseApp: FirebaseApp = this.firestore.firestore.app;

    initializeFirestore(firebaseApp, {}, secondDbName);

    firestoreInstance$.subscribe((instance) => {
      console.log("instance:", instance);
    });
  }
}
```

And been trying to get a proper firestore instance of a non-default database. I followed the suggestions mentioned by the repo:

> In theory there are three APIs that should allow this in the new API:
>
> 1. You should be able to inject `FirestoreInstances` into your component to get an array of the firestore instances. They would have
>    had to have been initialized before your component.
> 2. There's an observable, firestoreInstance$ which you can import from `@angular/fire/firestore`, you can filter the observable
>    emissions to grab the database you want.
> 3. You can use the same API as you would the JS SDK to get access ([getFirestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getfirestore) and [initializeFirestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#initializefirestore), see the databaseId arg), just
>    import from @angular/fire/firestore rather than firebase/firestore so
>    you get Zone.js fixes.
>
> That said, we only unblocked use against Firebase JS SDK v10 the other
> day with the release of AngularFire v16. So I've not had a chance to
> experiment here yet.

`instance` above gets logged multiple times, one of which is the database I need. But, the shape of the object only has three keys:

`app`, `toJSON` and `type`

[image: code preview]

Using:
Angular 15 + Angular Fire 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I rewrote all queries I have to use the modular syntax, and refactored away from all things compat. Here's how you make your code connected to any database in the same project:

```
import { getApp, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from "@angular/fire/app";
import { initializeFirestore, provideFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(config)),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const app = getApp();
      const dbName = "db-name";
      const providedFirestore = initializeFirestore(app, {}, dbName);
      return providedFirestore;
    }),
  ]
})
```

Then in your services:

```
import { inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Firestore, getDocs } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  orderBy,
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class MyService {
  private firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);

  getUsers() {
    return getDocs(
      query(
        collection(this.firestore, "Users"),
        where("some_id", "==", "id"),
        orderBy("created_at", "asc")
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This also can let you connect to multiple databases and inject them as needed.